# In Typescript, how to let generic type default to nothing?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define a type `Result` which has an optional Data type.

My current type definition is:

```js
type Result<Data = void> = {
  tx: string,
  data: Data
}
```

But it has the following issues (line #2 is not passed):

```js
const ret: Result<{userId: string}> = {tx: "123", data: {userId: "456"}} // it is GOOD!
const ret: Result = {tx: "123"} // it will complain missing data, how can we pass it?
```

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: make data optional like this `data?: Data`

Comment: @blessanm86 That would undesirably permit `Result<number> = { tx: '123' }`, right?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Well depends on how strong do u want the type to be. But ya ur solution is better in that regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void` does not make sense in a context where an expression value is expected - void is like saying there is no value at all (not `undefined` or `null`, but that there isn't any value associated with it). So typing a property value as `void` doesn't make sense, just like

```
const foo: void = <anything>
```

doesn't make sense - unless you explicitly use something that returns a void type, which is really weird (better not to pass it at all).

One approach is to use a conditional object type:

```
type Result<Data = void> = void extends Data
  ? {
    tx: string
  }
  : {
    tx: string,
    data: Data
  };

const ret: Result<{ userId: string }> = { tx: "123", data: { userId: "456" } } // Good
const ret2: Result = { tx: "123" } // Good
const ret3: Result = { tx: "123", data: 'foo' } // Bad
```